# Facebook's oEmbed endpoint syntax error as Invalid or unexpected token

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

i am trying to embed facebook video after getting the embeddable code from oembed html attribute.you can get that by giving get request to https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video/oembed.json?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Ffacebook%2Fvideos%2F10153231379946729%2F&

```
<div id=\ "fb-root\"></div>\n
<script>

    (function (d, s, id) {
    \n
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]; \n
        if (d.getElementById(id))
            return; \n
        js = d.createElement(s);
        js.id = id; \n
        js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v3.1'; \n
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs); \n
    }
        (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

</script>

<div class=\ "fb-video\" data-href=\ "https://www.facebook.com/JayShettyIW/videos/2041157322865389/\">
    <blockquote cite=\ "https://www.facebook.com/JayShettyIW/videos/2041157322865389/\" 
        class=\ "fb-xfbml-parse-ignore\">
            <a href=\ "https://www.facebook.com/JayShettyIW/videos/2041157322865389/\">
                If You&#039;ve Been Hurt Watch This
            </a>
            <p>
                It reflects on what they are, not what you are.
            </p>
            <a href=\ "https://www.facebook.com/JayShettyIW/\">
                Jay 
            </a>
        ಅವರಿಂದ ಈ ದಿನದಂದು ಪೋಸ್ಟ್ ಮಾಡಲಾಗಿದೆ ಮಂಗಳವಾರ, ಜೂನ್ 5, 2018
    </blockquote>
</div>
```

i get syntax error as when i directly embed the code whereas when i console.log() the above code and include it works fine
[image]

Comment: why those backslashes in the id, and what about those line breaks? (\n) - hopefully, they are not really in your code? and where is the exact error message?

Comment: give get request to https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video/oembed.json?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Ffacebook%2Fvideos%2F10153231379946729%2F& you will get the above

Comment: Yes, and that is JSON, so you have to properly _parse_ it as such, and not just copy&paste parts out of it as text.